# Is there such a thing as a 7-5 suspension?

Tags: voice-leading

It is not shown in my harmony books but I sometimes use it in my composition. A 7-6 suspension is very common but that suspension resolves to 63 chords. Is a 7 suspension also able to resolve to the 5 of a 53 chord?

Comment: Please add a notated example of what you're describing.

Comment: Yes, an example please. Especially how you get to the 7, to show it actually is a suspension.

Comment: Please see dictionary for a 7-6 suspension https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/7-6_suspension. This is a very common suspension in music theory so no other example should be necessary.

Comment: We're all clear on what a 7-6 suspension is. We want to see how you're getting a 7-5 suspension.

Comment: just take any texbook one you know and instead of 7 resolving to 6 it resolves to 5.. naturally a 53 chord will result not a 63 chord.

Comment: "instead of 7 resolving to 6 it resolves to 5": By leaping down a third?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the classical definition of a suspension allows resolution other than by step.  But if you want to extend the definition to include what you're doing, that's fine by me.  You might have got your wrists slapped in 1750. Not now, if it makes melodic sense.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no.  To be an actual 7-6 suspension, there would need to be a 7th that resolves down by step, and this will naturally form a sixth.  No chord exists that has both a C as its root and an A as its fifth.

[image]

**However,** it is technically *possible.*. It could happens that the suspension resolves *and* the harmony changes at the same time.  So if the suspension were to happen over a C chord, and then the harmony changes to a D chord at the point of the resolution, you could get something like this.  I'm not sure whether you'd want to do this (as it results in a doubled third), but I don't see why it isn't possible.

[image]

- EDIT - the final interval number in this last example should be 5, not 6.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The last example is a 9-8 suspension is it not?

Comment: In the graphic with three examples, only the first shows a 7-6 suspension. The 7 and 6 in such a suspension are, by definition, in relation to the bass.

Comment: @Aaron your are correct!  I removed that part.

Comment: @armani I removed the graphic, which mislabelled a few suspensions.

Comment: Have you got something against the C6 chord?

Comment: No, @Laurence but remember the OP wants the resolution to be the fifth of the chord

Comment: @Laurence A C6 is also Am7 in 2nd inversion. In Classical music does such a chord even exist?

Comment: @armani As you suspect, C6 is not a chord in classical theory. Am7 yes, but C6 no.

Comment: C6 has been in mainstream use for at least 100 years.  Many of the 'rules' of 18th century harmony are still applicable!

Comment: Laurence, maybe the way the chord has been named has changed

Answer (score 0):

A dissonant(classical) suspension, by definition, must resolve by step, normally downwards. There is such thing as a 7-8 suspension(Bach uses this type of suspension to great effect in the final chorus of the St Matthew Passion), but it is considered weak, and far rarer than its downward, unanticipated counterparts. What you describe is not a suspension: it is simply a held dissonance that arbitrarily resolves. Nuggethead's example is technically an exception. There is another way that you could make an exception, which is more likely to show up in real music; a dominant 7th suspension chord moving to a deceptive cadence. Something like this:

[image: Example]

But that falls, as I already said, into suspension chords, and is a different beast altogether in terms of intervals. So if we're talking about suspensions meant to *delay* a certain harmony, no, a 7th to a fifth will never happen. If we're talking about suspensions meant to *create* a certain new harmony(suspension chords), a 7-5 will sometimes happen.

Comment: THanks Tim. To me a 7-8 suspension is a bass suspension. It is when the bass forms a seventh with one of th eupper parts and resolves downwards to an octave.

Comment: There's no suspension in this example. There is a Bb common tone between to chords followed by a D minor chord. To be a suspension, the Bb would have to be a non-chord tone in the C7 chord.

Comment: @armani Both are 7-8 suspensions, though we usually think of 7-8 suspensions as an upper voice suspending an octave, especially the leading tone at a V-I cadence. By the way, the original poster of an answer will always be on the far right.

Comment: @Aaron No, a suspension is not necessarily a non-chord tone. Not only are there consonant suspensions, there are also suspension chords where a new harmony arises from the suspended note.

Comment: @OprenStein non-chord tone and dissonance are not the synonymous. Suspensions involve non-chord tones, which may or may not be dissonant against the bass.

Comment: @Aaron Again, suspensions are not necessarily non-chord tones. They can create a new chord, and we have to decide whether or not to call the new "chord" a suspension of a single chord or a new harmonic function. If we move from IV to V 4/2, and suspend scale degree 1 and 6, there is an incidental ii 6/5 which makes sense functionally as a strong predominant followed by a dominant. If we have a 7-8 suspension of the leading tone in a V-I cadence, we technically create a I7 chord. But we decide not to count it due to it's functional irrelevance. Neither of these examples are strictly non-chord..

Comment: ...tones, but they're still suspensions even though they do create new chords.

Comment: @OprenStein In the IV to V4-2 case, the theory would consider the incidental ii6-5 as a chord in its own right, so it would not be considered a suspension. The duration of the chord isn't important in determining its functional presence. In the 7-8 case, the theory says that the (major) 7 is a non-chord tone, but since it moves up to 8, it's (technically a retardation, but for our purposes, yes, a suspension. (We can *suspend* the requirement that suspensions resolve downward.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144989/discussion-between-aaron-and-oprenstein).